# Distance between highest and lowest point on rotated square

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

I have a square and I want to know the vertical distance between the highest point and the lowest point. The square is $10 \times 10$ cm.
The amount of degrees the square is rotated can be anything, but I need a formula that always works no matter the amount of degrees it is rotated.

Does anyone know a formula to calculate this?

So in this picture I would need to know the length of the red line:

[image]

Comment: Are you just looking for the length of the diagonal of a 10x10 square?

Comment: @mwalth no please read the question carefully, im sorry im not the best at explaining.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "perfectly horizontal to the other side"? Parallel to? A picture would be helpful.

Comment: @mwalth i edited a picture in my question

Comment: I've added a better diagram to the question. You can use [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry) to make better quality diagrams.

Comment: For reference, $CBAD$ is a square, and $CE$ is parallel to $AF$ with $EF$ being perpendicular to both $CE$ and $AF$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the square is rotated by an angle of $\theta$. You can draw a square $B$ that just touches the vertex of your original square, as in here ($\theta$ would be angle $STY$):

[image: square]

Thus, the height you are looking is the sum of $XS$ and $SY$, which are equal to the shortest sides of triangle STY. Thus, the height equals $(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))L,$ where $L$ is the side length of the original square (in your case, 10 cm).

Comment: in this case square B would be ZYXW right?

Comment: Yes, ZYXW is square B.

Comment: is "(cos(θ)+sin(θ))L" the blank formula?

Comment: Yes, that's the formula.

Comment: That is what i was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the angle $\theta$ that the square has been rotated relative to the horizontal. A small amount of trig then shows that the distance between the two lines is $10( \sin \theta +\cos \theta)$. The smallest the distance can be occurs when $\theta=0$, and is just 10, and the largest value occurs when $\theta = 45^\circ$ at which point it is $10\sqrt2$.